# Facebook Like iframe issue

Tags: facebook-like

We're having an issue today, the face book like iframe appears not to be working on a few of our sites:

- http://www.escapestudios.co.uk/23-mari-tips-in-23-days-on-twitter/
- http://www.winterson.co.uk/blog/2011/08/introducing-sophie-breitmeyer-at-winterson/

Anyone else experiencing the same problem?

Comment: the like buttons on your two links seem to be functioning correctly...

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been [logged](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20213) with Facebook.